# using col function in pyspark to view all columns

Tags: sql, pyspark

i have a dataframe with multiple columns but when m trying to iterate over those columns using col function its throwing an error

```
input: df.columns
output: ['Serial No.',
 'GRE Score',
 'TOEFL Score',
 'University Rating',
 'SOP',
 'LOR ',
 'CGPA',
 'Research',
 'Chance of Admit ']
```

i get these names of the columns but i need to make some changes to these columns for which m trying to iterate over them

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to apply col function like

Comment: for c in df.columns: print(col(c)). but this is throwing an error whereas it works fine with my friend whose using the same code

Answer (score 0):

Just using a normal for loop

```py
df = ...
for c in df.columns:
  df = df.withColumn(c + '__new', F.col(c) + 1)
```